# to find Second last value of a string in number or character

Tags: notepad++

I need to find out whether the the second last value in number or digit in notepad++
example :
abc,abc,123,123
abc,abc,abc,123
def,feg,345,123
It should highlight me the below lines i,e
abc,abc,123,123
def,feg,345,123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the regular expression find with:

```
^.*,\d+,[^,]+$
```

It should give the results you seek.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bH8zP0)

Comment: @user3223672 You're welcome :)